# Aviso ao chamar o método orderBy de forma estática

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Na interface do PHPStorm é exibido uma mensagem de aviso informando que estou chamando o método orderBy de forma estática, porém, este não é estático. Minha chamada:

```
Artigo::orderBy('edicao', 'desc')->paginate(25);
```

Isso estaria "errado"? Ou teria que fazer:

```
(new Artigo)->orderBy('edicao', 'desc')->paginate(25);
```

Obs: estou utilizando Laravel 5.6

Comment: Para acessar um método ou campo de objeto, você deveria usar o operador seta `->` Eu só vi o operador de resolução de escopo `::` sendo usado para determinar métodos e Campos de classe/estáticos em php

Comment: Isso é chamado Facade dá uma busca na documentação do Laravel

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/facades de uma lida e ignore mensagem do PHPStorm não tem problema usar a primeira forma

Comment: Dei uma olhada em grandes projetos, é normal/comum essa abordagem pelo que pude observar.

Comment: Não tem problema, a primeira forma está correta sim.

Answer (score 0):

A forma como você está fazendo não é errada, mas acho que a melhor forma de fazer a chamada dos models seria chamar eles no __constructor ex.:

```
private $artigoModel

public function __constructor(Artigo $artigoModel){
    $this->artigoModel = $artigoModel
}
```

Assim você consegue fazer a chamada por $this->artigoModel em todo o código e não precisa ficar instanciando várias vezes caso precise dele em mais de uma função.